# I need Spring AOP pointcut annotation that matches this

Tags: spring, aop

any public method, any return type, partial class name match, any method, taking session as the first arg.

I came up with `@Before(value="execution(public * *ServiceImpl.*(*.PlayerSession,..))")`

this doesn't work. but when I change it to `@Before(value="execution(public * com.mycompany.mypkg.IdServiceImpl.*(*.PlayerSession,..))")` it works. can I get an explanation for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this instead:

```
@Before(value = "execution(public * *..*ServiceImpl.*(*..PlayerSession, ..))")
```

you need to add `*..` so that spring would search for your `*ServiceImpl` service in any package

note: just for convenience I have added it also before your PlayerSession object